# Help to simplify the expression

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$${(b+c+d)^4-(a+c+d)^4+(d+a+b)^4-(a+b+c)^4+(a-d)^4-(b-c)^4\over (b+c+d)^2-(a+c+d)^2+(d+a+b)^2-(a+b+c)^2+(a-d)^2-(b-c)^2}=F_{a,b,c,d}$$

where condition: **$ad=bc$**

Can someone please help to simplify the above equation, I tried to expand, but it seems to get more and more messy.

I try some values for $F_{a,b,c,d}$ the result is an integer, it shows that they have a common factor, which if I find it, this equation can be simplify further.

Comment: $$\dfrac ab=\dfrac cd $$  $$=k$$(say)

Comment: First of all, what is the inspiration behind the search for a closed form of such an expression?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ramanujan6-10-8Identity.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hirschhorn3-7-5Identity.html from these pages @Rohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $a\neq 0$ we can substitute $d=bc/a$, so that
$$
F_{a,b,c,d}=\frac{1}{a^2}\left(2a^4 + 4a^3b + 2a^3c + 2a^2b^2 + 4a^2bc + a^2c^2 + 2ab^2c + b^2c^2 \right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n:=(b+c+d)^n -(a+c+d)^n + (d+a+b)^n - (a+b+c)^n +(a-d)^n - (b-c)^n.$
Then $f_4 = f_2\;((a+b+c+d)^2 + (a+b)^2 - 2cd) + 6\;(ad-bc)\;(2ab+ad+bc-(c+d)^2).$